# How to filter in Firebase Realtime Database in a dynamic deeper node

Tags: javascript, firebase-realtime-database

I have orders structure in the firebase realtime database like this
Orders/year/userid/orderid and I want to filter all orders from all users with condition orders/year that shippingStatus equalto some status below is my code and I always got null value any idea please?

[image]

```
 const db = getDatabase(app);
  const _query = query(
    ref(db, `orders/${year}`),
    orderByChild("shippingStatus"),
    equalTo(shippingStatus)
  );
  
 get(_query)
    .then((snapshot) => {
      const result = snapshot.val();
      console.log(result);
    })
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Firebase Realtime Database can only filter on values that are at a known, fixed path under each direct child node of the path where you execute the query.

So if you know the `0AW...` key, you can query all child nodes directly under `2023/0AW...` on their `shippingStatus` value - but there is no way to query over all grandchild nodes in the year for their `shippingStatus` property. You'll have to create a flat list to allow this use-case.

Also see:

- [Firebase Query Double Nested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27207059/firebase-query-double-nested)